# my current array format is not being interpreted by datatables using aaData format

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, datatable

I'm using aaData array datasource , while displaying the value into table only one character is appearing. why is this displaying only one character? It is supposed to display [0] element. May be this is a simple question, but its looks hard to me. Please help me.

```
data value format : ["T moniter","Software","W CPU","Software","Global","Softe"]
jQuery.ajax({
 url : '<s:url action="part" method="finder" />',
 dataType : 'json',
 success : function(data){
 alert(data);
 var obj = JSON.stringify(data);
 alert(obj);
$('tbody tr:nth-child(odd)').addClass('odd');
var prodTable = $('#products').dataTable({
            "aaData": data,
            "bDeferRender": true,
            "bPaginate": false,
            "aoSearchCols" : false,
            "bDeferRender": true,
            "aoColumnDefs": [
                {"fnRender": function(o, val){
                console.log("fnRender");
                        console.log(o.aData[0]);
                        return o.aData[0];
                    },
                    "sClass":"Nbr first", "aTargets": [ 0 ]

                    }]


            });
```

i'm getting null values in the datatable.

Comment: Anybody have idea why is this data not interpreted with datatable ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you found it before you'll see my answer :

`var obj = JSON.stringify(data);`

`"aaData": data,`

You stringify your data, and you don't use it.

The correct way is :

```
"aaData": obj,
```

or

```
"aaData": JSON.stringify(data),
```

Hope i answer to your question.